# Using SignalR to communicate between Server(asp mvc framework 4.5) and client (console app with framework 3.5))

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, signalr

I have an ASP MVC application that runs in 4.5 framework
this application should communicate in real time with an other console application that using 4.5 framework also
for this reason I use SignalR
in the server(mvc application) I installed  Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR" version 2.1.2
In the client (Console App ) I installed  Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Client version="2.2.1"
this runs well 
But problems start when My Customer required that the console application should run in .Net Framework 3.5 not in 4.5

when I tried to migrate console application to 3.5 framework , the communcation between server and client does not  work

I have create a new console app with 3.5 framework and I use "Nivot.SignalR.Client.Net35" version="2.0.0" 
and  Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR -Version 1.2.2 in server but I have this Message=You are using a version of the client that isn't compatible with the server. Client version 1.3, server version 1.2.
       Source=Nivot.SignalR.Client.Net35
when I Use Package Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR -Version 2.0.1 in server I have this message :An unhandled exception of type 'System.AggregateException' occurred in System.Threading.dll
More information: TaskExceptionHolder_UnhandledException

How to resolve this problems?
Is there an example that use signalR with my configuration?

Comment: Did you inspect the Inner Exceptions property of the AggregateException to see what actually went wrong? An AggregateException is a container for one or more exceptions.

Answer (score 1):

SignalR requires at least .NET Framework 4. It relies heavily on async/await and Tasks which are not supported on .NET Framework 3.5. It should be possible to write a SignalR client for .NET Framework 3.5 but it is quite a task (especially that you would have to manage threads on your own).

Comment: Is there an example that use signalR with framework 4.5 on server and 3.5 on client ?

Comment: No, because SignalR does not support .NET Framework 3.5

Comment: Ok , Is there any solutions tu establish communication in real time beteew server and client ? is there any examples?

Comment: Assuming you want samples for .NET Framework 3.5 I don't think there are any because SignalR does not support .NET Framework 3.5. You can try implement a client yourself - here is the SignalR protocol description I wrote: https://blog.3d-logic.com/2015/03/29/signalr-on-the-wire-an-informal-description-of-the-signalr-protocol/. You would have to to implement something that follows that protocol. You could use C#, JavaScript and C++ client as your reference implementations.